# How to load balance Google Cloud Run for multi-region architecture

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

I'm trying to create a multi-region Google Cloud Run setup and can't find any documentation.

My goal is creating an Google HTTPS Load Balancer and map the targets as my 3 Google Cloud Run instances.

```
https://lb.test.com/ > 

eu.test.com > Europe Cloud Run
na.test.com > North America Cloud Run
sa.test.com > South America Cloud Run
```

Problem is, I can't find the option of mapping my HTTPS load balancer into my Cloud Run instances.

If this is not possible yet, can I use an external DNS LB such as AWS Route 53?

Thanks!

Comment: Stuff are in progress. Stay tuned!!!!

Comment: Please consider picking an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping load balancer to cloud run is possible now. This can be achieved by creating NEGs (Network Endpoint Groups) which points to a cloud run service.

I have implemented this today, and came across this thread. To find out how to implement this follow instructions in

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs#creating_the

Comment: From Review: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link [may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently published a guide on this on our official documentation: http://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions

The solution involves adding the newly introduced "Serverless Network Endpoint Groups" as backends to your load balancer.

Comment: What about multiple cloud run services for the same region?. Looks like NEG does not allow this, is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can use a Google HTTPS Load Balancer to make cloud run service multiregional (HTTPS Load Balancer supports only compute engine vm as backend). Your question was very interesting and I did some research.

The only useful documents I found about this topic:

[Running Multi-Region Apps on Google Cloud (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCvzUTmKakQ).

[Going Multi-Regional in Google Cloud Platform](https://medium.com/swlh/going-multi-regional-in-google-cloud-platform-18495a833838)

They are explaining how you can make a cloud service multiregional using Apigee (some proxy servers HA Proxy, Nginx).

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of external solutions, was wondering if and when Google will make it happen. It seems extremely suited for this sort of solution. I will probably solve this temporary with AWS Route 53 (although Google is using Anycast and geolocation calculations mistakes will probably occur) or maybe using client side latency tests.